# Parser for C# code to evaluate testability?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, parsing, testability

I'm trying to write a program that will allow me to give it a collection of C# code files and analyze them for [testability problems](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/).  I'm starting out with just the 4 provided in the preceding link.

The end goal is to create a report of all the files, any testability problems they might have, and specific code annotations on where these problems may be observed (if applicable).  What I would like help with is choosing some tools to make the job of parsing the code easier; I can read everything in as a string but making order out of the code to analyze it is very difficult in that situation.

I have evaluated the following things so far:

- [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28VS.80%29.aspx) (does not function for anything that's not a .dll, a few test projects are web projects with testable logic in their controllers or presenters)
- [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) (not what I need; this does not help identify problems)
- [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/Pex/default.aspx) (ditto)
- [NRefactory](https://github.com/icsharpcode/NRefactory/) (Might be interesting, but documentation and usage information is nonexistant and the demos are broken, even with gtk/mono installed on windows)
- [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) (The .Parse method returns a NotImplementedException)

As far as what I'm looking for:

I would at least like to have detection of basic object structures and accessor objects to navigate around in (e.g., a *File* object has a *Namespace* property with a collection of *Classes*, each *Class* has collections of *Members*, *Constructors*, and *Methods*, etc).  Obviously if there are tools that can get more and more elaborate and detailed that would be amazing, but just having these things available to allow me to process small, focused strings would be a complete god-send.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [CodeDom.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.aspx)

Comment: I think you are going about it the wrong way.  I think you should approach it from the stand point where its not possible to create code that does not match your coding guidlines that is NOT testable.  I had no problem setting up FxCop in huge solutions both WPF/Win32/dll projects.

Comment: @Ramhound How to test/analyze controllers/presenters in this case then?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yeah, that's where CSharpCodeProvider came from, and parsing that returns an NIE - I was more than a little angry about that when I saw it.  I sort of gave up at that point though; it's possible I just gave up to soon. If you have a suggestion for making CodeDom work I am all ears!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use prerelease code, you might want to check out [roslyn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2011/10/19/introducing-the-microsoft-roslyn-ctp.aspx), i.e. "compiler as a service":

> Traditionally, compilers are black boxes – source code goes in one end and object files or assemblies come out the other end. The ***Roslyn [project] changes that model by opening up the Visual Basic and C# compilers as APIs.*** These APIs allow tools and end-users to share in the wealth of information the compilers have about code.

Mind you, however, that interpreting what you get (a syntax tree) might still be a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

[NRefactory 5](https://github.com/icsharpcode/NRefactory) offers roughly the same analysis features for C# as Roslyn for C#, "only" the ability to compile to IL is missing.

Not sure what's going on with the GTK-based demo; so I've fixed the WinForms-based demo and added that back to the solution.

For parsing C# code, use `new CSharpParser().Parse(sourceCode, "filename.cs")`. This will give you the full syntax tree for the file; i.e. a `CompilationUnit` root node with `NamespaceDeclaration`s as children. Use the demo application to see what the tree looks like.

If you want to detect certain code patterns (your testability issues), you can use NRefactory's pattern matching feature. (see `doc/Pattern Matching.html` for details)

I think NRefactory with pattern matching might work better than Roslyn for your usecase.